# css3 Keyframes animation taking a pause in transform translate

Tags: css, animation, css-animations, keyframe

I am trying to animate a man (character) which is first at out of the box then it translates from left to the middle of the box and translating it in Y to move it up and down (which should look like it is flying the problem area) two times and again translate to the right side.  I am using keyframes to do this and on percentages performing the animation. When man goes up and down (which should be like floating/flying in air). But it takes a pause when it reaches to the max position and comes back to the min position .

Please tell me how to remove the pause so it will look smooth.

my keyframe

```
  @-webkit-keyframes flyCharacter {

        30% {
            transform: translateX(-180%) translateY(-70%);
        }

        /*49.9%{transform: translateX(-180%) translateY(-65%);}*/

        50% {
            transform: translateX(-180%) translateY(-65%);
        }

        /*69.9%{transform: translateX(-180%) translateY(-69%);}*/
        70% {
            transform: translateX(-180%) translateY(-70%);
        }
        90% {
            transform: translateX(-180%) translateY(-65%);
        }

        100% {
            transform: translateX(-310%) translateY(-150%);
        }
    }
```

at first position of character is at left:100%

please correct me where I doing it wrong . I need it to be smooth.

Comment: We need to see the `animation` property and its value also. Better create a demo.

Comment: yes create a jsfiddle.

Comment: here is the code pen demo .. please check it ..   http://codepen.io/rjsnh1522/pen/NrdwrM

Comment: It is behaving the exact same way as your keyframe rule instructs it to. I don't see any sort of pause or anything like that.

Comment: actually I want it to float up and down like he is flying so can guide me how to do this . please. When I go close to the screen it seems that it is taking a pause to change it direction (stops for fraction of second) I want to remove that.

Comment: You want that to fly from bottom to top, at-present it's right to left.